# How do I undersample more than one time and compare the results from each sampling

Tags: python, list, for-loop, scikit-learn, sampling

I have three lists which I would like to fix the "random_state" at a time while running the remaining two lists as shown in the expected output. Which part I should edit in order to get expected output? The purpose is to determine the RF performance from each under sampling.

```
number = list(range(41,55))
data = [df_AFC,df_AF,df_ESF,df_EXF,df_F,df_GF,df_KRFC,df_KRF,df_MF,df_PF,df_SFC,df_SF]
name = ['AFC','AF','ESF','EXF','F','GF','KRFC','KRF','MF','PF','SFC','SF']
```

```
def remove_low_variance(input_data, threshold=0.1):
    selection = VarianceThreshold(threshold)
    selection.fit(input_data)
    return input_data[input_data.columns[selection.get_support(indices=True)]]
```

```
result = []
for k, i, j in zip(number,data,name):
        # rus = RandomUnderSampler(sampling_strategy="not minority") # String
        rus = RandomUnderSampler(sampling_strategy=1, random_state=k) # Numerical value
        x = i.drop('class', axis=1)
        y = i['class']        
        x_res, y_res = rus.fit_resample(x, y)
        #replace with x_res, y_res from now on
        remove_low_variance(x_res, threshold=0.1)
        x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x_res, y_res, test_size=0.2, 
  random_state=42)
        x_train.shape, x_test.shape
        model = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=500, random_state=42)
        model.fit(x_train, y_train)
        y_train_pred = model.predict(x_train)
        y_test_pred = model.predict(x_test)
        mcc_train = matthews_corrcoef(y_train, y_train_pred)
        #print(mcc_train)
        mcc_test = matthews_corrcoef(y_test, y_test_pred)
        #print(mcc_test)
        rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=500, random_state=42)
        cv_scores = cross_val_score(rf, x_train, y_train, cv=5)
        #print(cv_scores)
        mcc_cv = cv_scores.mean()
        #print(mcc_cv)
        random_state_balance = pd.Series(k, name='Random_state')
        FP_name = pd.Series(j, name='Fingerprint')
        model_name = pd.Series(['Random forest'], name='Name')
        mcc_train_series = pd.Series(mcc_train, name='MCC_train')
        mcc_cv_series = pd.Series(mcc_cv, name='MCC_cv')
        mcc_test_series = pd.Series(mcc_test, name='MCC_test')
        performance_metrics = pd.concat([random_state_balance,FP_name, model_name, 
        mcc_train_series, mcc_cv_series, 
        mcc_test_series], axis=1)
        result.append(performance_metrics)
```

**Current output**

[image]

**Expected output**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate over the list Fingerprint, something like the below code:

```
for n in name:
     result = []
     for k, i, j in zip(number,data,name):
           # rus = RandomUnderSampler(sampling_strategy="not minority") # String
           rus = RandomUnderSampler(sampling_strategy=1, random_state=k) # Numerical value
           x = i.drop('class', axis=1)
```